# Snap tool seems not working for edge loop?

Tags: modeling, snapping, looping

i can use snap tool for boundary edge, but for edge loop, it does not work. all the settings were same when it works.

And if i select the bottom capping loop, double tap G, the snap tool does not work as well. So it seems to be snap tool does not work with double tap G??
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it doesn't work with double G but it should work in your first case if for example you type GZ, so maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You can do a post about this on right-click-select.